# content_fallback for Child-Objects in Extbase when Parent is not translated

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

What do I have to do to get a translated Child from an Record which is not translated?

Default Language is German (0), Second Language is English (1).
Currently I've products which work for all languages. The Categories are translated.

The English Page is showing the German Records, but also the German Childs, not the English ones. What am I getting wrong here?

English is set to content_fallback.

TYPO3 Version is 10.4.26

Comment: Same problem here, hope someone can help. I got this error after Ugrade from T3 9.5 to 10.4 with my own Extbase Extension.

It happens, because of removing "consistentTranslationOverlayHandling" in v10.

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.5/Important-82363-MakeExtBaseTranslationHandlingConsistentWithTyposcript.html

Comment: But it already worked for me in 10. And what I found out is, when I translate one record, the others with the same category for magically translated.

Comment: Interesting that it have already worked in v10. Have you tried downgrading the Core to lower Version like 10.4.19 to check if it working there again? Maybe it is a bug in some of the latest security patches?

Comment: This extension might help: https://github.com/georgringer/extbase_with_no_l10n_parent